# Change UTC timezone to SGT timezone in Cesiumjs

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

in cesium the default timezone is UTC. So I want to change the UTC timezone to SGT timezone....Can you correct my mistake and  my code is found below.. SGT Timezone is GMT+8.. I want to see the Singapore time on the timeline and the clock view... Also i want the UTC replaced with SGT. here is my code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Use correct character set. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Tell IE to use the latest, best version. -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!-- Make the application on mobile take up the full browser screen and disable user scaling. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>SGT Timezone </title>
  <script src="../Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <style>
      @import url(../Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);
      html, body, #cesiumContainer {
          width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
  <script>
    var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
    //SST timezone
    var TZcode = 'SGT';
    //Construct a new Date
    var UTCoffset = new Date();
    //Return the timezone difference between UTC and Local Time:
    UTCoffset = -UTCoffset.getTimezoneOffset();
    //Construct a Julian Date
    var UTCscratch = new Cesium.JulianDate();

    // Date formatting to a global form
    function localeDateTimeFormatter(datetime, viewModel, ignoredate) {
    if(UTCoffset) datetime = Cesium.JulianDate.addMinutes(datetime, UTCoffset, UTCscratch);
    var gregorianDT = Cesium.JulianDate.toGregorianDate(datetime), objDT;
    if(ignoredate)
    objDT = '';
    else {
    objDT = new Date(gregorianDT.year, gregorianDT.month-1, gregorianDT.day);
    objDT = gregorianDT.day + ' ' + objDT.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "short" }) + ' ' + gregorianDT.year;
    if(viewModel || gregorianDT.hour+gregorianDT.minute === 0)
    return objDT;
    objDT += ' ';
    }
    return objDT + Cesium.sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d "+TZcode, gregorianDT.hour, gregorianDT.minute, gregorianDT.second);
    }
    function localeTimeFormatter(time, viewModel) {
    return localeDateTimeFormatter(time, viewModel, true);
    }
    viewer.animation.viewModel.dateFormatter = localeDateTimeFormatter;
    viewer.animation.viewModel.timeFormatter = localeTimeFormatter;
    viewer.timeline.makeLabel = function(time) { return localeDateTimeFormatter(time); }

    document.querySelectorAll('.cesium-timeline-ticLabel').forEach(function(i) {
    i.textContent = i.textContent.replace("UTC", "SGT");
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

THE default timezone is UTC thus I want to change to SGT timezone which GMT +8

Comment: Hi, has anybody solved this one? I have the same problem. :-(

Comment: Actually, this code works but you have to move the slider first to the right and drag it again at the beginning. After doing this, the dates on the slider are updated to the correct local values. Its like the code

    viewer.timeline.makeLabel = function(time) { 
      return localeDateTimeFormatter(time); 
    }    
is not triggered during start-up